# SSH into oDroid/Ubuntu not understanding common commands

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

The only way I can describe this is weird. Using SSH from my Ubuntu computer to my Ubuntu oDroid. This is the first time I've SSH'd into this oDroid. I can login successfully. Here's the problem:

Through SSH I can't use the history command, but with a keyboard and monitor directly hooked up to the oDroid I can. SSHing from Ubuntu to Ubuntu. Overall the SSH line looks weird to me, but I have no way to check that. Here's what it looks like:

```
Last login: Sun Mar 19 16:33:24 2017
$ 
$ ls
opencv
$ history
-sh: 7: history: not found
$ logout
-sh: 8: logout: not found
$ exit
Connection to [blah] closed
```

**So, the question is what's going on with this SSH session?**

If it matters, on the client side (or my computer, w/e) I'm using Terminator and ZSH, though I've never had problems with this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, the question is what's going on with this SSH session?

There is nothing wrong with the ssh session. The difference is that you are running very limited shell (`sh` -- default for that user). You can try to start `bash` or `zsh` to get more features.